# Barn Bicycle Find Information appreciated

Tags: identify-this-bike

I am seeking information on this bicycle found in our farm shed.  The bike is blue with very thin white stripes.  There is a serial number on the top of the bike where the seat attaches.  It is 4E8736[image: Side view of bicycle]  It is located in Canada, possibly Canadian or US made. Any information greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can't help much but clean it up and it would make a stunning  retro/single speed statement

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: I will try to get clearer photographs.  Thanks to all who are doing their best to help.  Would like to know make & model, and if it's worth restoring (someone is interested in making it a décor item, painting over it .. and maybe that IS it's value???   ... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Can't tell a great deal from that picture alone... Can you supply some clearer pictures?
in daylight side on view looking at the chainring side would be best.

The tubing looks a bit too angular to be a **Western Flyer** - but some of those did have dual top tube.

Those slim rear stays look like **Raleigh** or **RMI Roadster.** 
Maybe even a **Humber**... although, I've not seen one with twin top tube.

What size are the tyres? it doesn't look old enough but if they are 28" there's a possibility it could an old **Elgin.**

If you can provide more information I can try to provide a better identification.

Thanks

Comment: I will try to get clearer photographs. Thanks to all who are doing their best to help. Would like to know make & model, and if it's worth restoring (someone is interested in making it a décor item, painting over it .. and maybe that IS it's value??? ... Thank you!

Comment: Personally I think it would be a shame to use this bike for decoration only. If it were me I'd like to restore this beauty to her former glory - have a look at this... a Vintage Harley Davidson bicycle, it could turn out to be one of those if your lucky...  http://www.nostalgic.net/restoration-of-a-1918-harley-davidson-bicycle-part-1